# Galleria starting image slides back to first image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-gallery, galleria

I'm using Galleria image gallery on my website.
The problem is: When I run galleria first time, and the initial image is not first, Galleria shows the initial for a moment and then slides back to the first image. When i click on thumbs more, Galleria acts correctly, so this happens only first time. Here is the code I use to initialise galleria:

```
$('.thumbnail').live('click', function(){   

            var image_number = getNumber($(this).attr('id'));
            Galleria.ready(function(options) {
                this.show(image_number);
            });
            Galleria.run('#galleria');
            $('#galleria_frame').show();    
           });
```

getNumber is my function that returns the number of image in gallery, first image has number 0, second - number 1 etc.
where is my mistake? Why does galleria slide back to first image when I click on the .thumbnail the first time?

Comment: Try to provide your example here http://jsfiddle.net/
This info isn't enough

Comment: can't model the whole situation during the mass includes of scripts and pictures. just look please if I'm using the api correctly. I have read the documentation, but I may be mistaken in construction the initialization code.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

1) you are initializing Galleria multiple times (every time you click a thumbnail)

2) you are adding multiple listeners to the `ready` event, each time you tell galleria to show different images onload.

Try this instead:

```
$('.thumbnail').live('click', function(){   
    var image_number = getNumber($(this).attr('id')),
        instance = $('#galleria').data('galleria');

    // if Galleria already loaded, just show the index:
    if (instance) {
        instance.show(image_number);
    } else {
    // else fire up Galleria and pass the index as an option
        $('#galleria_frame').show();
        Galleria.run('#galleria', { show: image_number });
    }
});
```

Comment: When I utilize your example the second time I click on a thumbnail (where instance is true) the prev/next buttons no longer change the galleria images.

Thoughts?